# How to add transaction in jsr233 sampler in jmeter while using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am working with JSR233 for sFTP PE testing. following is a rough flow diagram.
Now I want to capture transaction time for file drop only. how can we achieve this in jmeter ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. Add a [SubResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#addSubResult-org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult-) for each step i.e.

   ```
   def establishConnection = new org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult()
   establishConnection.sampleStart()
   //code to establish connection
   establishConnection.setSampleLabel('Establish Connection')
   establishConnection.setSuccessful(true)
   establishConnection.sampleEnd()
   SampleResult.addSubResult(establishConnection)

   def dropFile = new org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult()
   dropFile.sampleStart()
   //code to drop the file
   dropFile.setSampleLabel('Drop File')
   dropFile.setSuccessful(true)
   dropFile.sampleEnd()
   SampleResult.addSubResult(dropFile)
   ```

   so you will get separate sub-result for each action:

   [image]
2. You can overwrite the JSR223 Sampler elapsed time with an arbitrary value from the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with the simple code like:

   ```
   prev.elapsedTime = 1000
   //replace 1000 with i.e. JMeter Variable holding the value of "drop file" event
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I just copied your code as is but it s not showing sampler label instead showing  jsr223 sampler -0 and jsr223 sampler - 1. any solution ?

Comment: Excuse me, but how this is connected to the original question? This is default JMeter behaviour, if you don't like it - either tick `Functional Test Mode` box on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level or add `subresults.disable_renaming=true` line to [*user.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

Comment: and also this error in log "ERROR o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice
"

Comment: yes this doesn't connected to original question but the answer. just wanted to resolve issue.